# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Facebook\Facebook::getUser()

Tags: php, facebook

Here is my code to get the user information and verify it from my database.

```
<?php
require_once ("autoload.php");
include_once 'config.php';

$facebook = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
      'app_id'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      'app_id'  => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
      'cookie' => true,
));
$parm = array(
    'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
    'redirect_uri' => 'https://apps.facebook.com/isensor/'
);

$uid = $facebook->getUser();

if($uid)
{
try {

    $fbme = $facebook->api('/me');
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    }
catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
    {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;

    }
}
```

I think facebook has removed the getUser() function. Can anyone please tell me how should I fix this?

Comment: https://apps.facebook.com/isensor
this is the link to the error.

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook docs ([here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_retrieve_user_profile)) refer to getGraphUser()

Answer (score 0):

You should use getGraphUser() because getUser() was deprecated on SDK v.3.2.3

```
$me = $response->getGraphUser();
echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();
```

Take a look at [Facebook Graph SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk)

I hope this helps.